# In what situation is the use of Directive required?

Tags: graphics

Sometimes I see code samples in the document or in this site using `Directive`, but I haven't yet find a case that `Directive` is necessary. Usually it can be replaced just by `List` (except for `Graphics` and `Graphics3D`, in which `Directive` can be replaced by `Sequence`) and their visual appearance won't change at all, though their `FullForm` structures will be different:

```
(* These samples are all modified from the examples in the document. *)

p[1] = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Thick, Dashed]];
p[2] = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Orange, Thick, Dashed}];
p[2] === p[1]
p[3] = 
  Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
    Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x, 2 Sin[x]}, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Medium, Italic]];
p[4] = 
  Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
    Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x, 2 Sin[x]} 
    LabelStyle -> {Medium, Italic}];
p[4] === p[3]
p[5] = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[φ] Sin[θ], Sin[φ] Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}, {φ, 0, 2 Pi}, {θ, 0, Pi}, 
    MeshShading -> {{Directive[Red, Specularity[White, 10]], 
      Directive[Green, Opacity[0.5]]}, {Blue, Yellow}}];
p[6] = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[φ] Sin[θ], Sin[φ] Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}, {φ, 0, 2 Pi}, {θ, 0, Pi}, 
    MeshShading -> {{{Red, Specularity[White, 10]}, 
      {Green, Opacity[0.5]}}, {Blue, Yellow}}];
p[6] === p[5]
p[7] = 
  Graphics[{Purple, Arrowheads[Large], Arrow[{{4, 3/2}, {0, 3/2}, {0, 0}}]}];
p[8] = 
  Graphics[{Directive[Purple, Arrowheads[Large]], Arrow[{{4, 3/2}, {0, 3/2}, {0, 0}}]}];
p[8] === p[7]
p[9] = 
  Graphics3D[
    Directive[Black, Thick, Dashed], 
     Line[{{-2, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 4}, {-2, 0, 2}}]}];
p[10] = 
  Graphics3D[{Black, Thick, Dashed, 
    Line[{{-2, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 4}, {-2, 0, 2}}]}];
p[10] === p[9]
Grid[Partition[p[#] & /@ Range@10, 2]]
```

> False
>   False
>   False
>   False
>   False

[image]

`Directive` was added in version 6, so its existence can't be a issue left over by history, so what's the significance of `Directive`? Is there a case where `Directive` is required? Does `Directive` give any advantage over `List` or `Sequence` that I haven't noticed?

Comment: For `Plot[]`, `Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Thick, Dashed]]` and `Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {{Orange, Thick, Dashed}}]` do yield the same effect, but `Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Orange, Thick, Dashed}]` does something a bit different.

Comment: I was just putting the same counterexample together when your comment appeared. The doc center says `Directive` is new in 6, but I seem to recall it in much older versions.

Comment: See also here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7226732#7226732

Comment: Even in ordinary `Plot` where, say, you plot two functions, using something like `PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red,Dashed],Directive[Green,Thick]}` can be easier to read at a glance than the corresponding version `PlotStyle -> {{Red,Dashed},{Green,Thick}}`with nested lists.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Directive` denotes a single compound graphics directive, which idea cannot otherwise be expressed, although the same effect can often be attained through multiple paths.  But then again, *Mathematica* offers multiple paths for many computations.

In a document one can define styles such as

```
myStyle = Directive[Thick, Blue, Opacity[0.5]]
```

and use them equally in `Plot`, `Graphics` etc. without having to apply `Sequence` or some other workaround.  In other words, if you think of the directives as a single style, you can write what you mean.

Another thing is that `Directive[..]` does not have the head `List`, which can be an advantage in postprocessing graphics.

Comment: Thanks for your observation concerning my answer. I have deleted it because I can't find a example where `Directive[]` is unavoidable.

Comment: I suppose the gist is that one can certainly choose **not** to use `Directive[]`, but one is left poorer and less expressive for it.

Answer (score 3):

I have run into a situation where using `Directive` works, but using a list fails. The following code, using `Directive`, works as expected.

```
Graph[{DirectedEdge[a, b], DirectedEdge[b, c], DirectedEdge[a, c]},
  VertexLabels -> "Name",
  VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, 14],
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1],
  GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"]
```

[image: graph.png]

However, when the directive is changed to a list, failure ensues.

```
Graph[{DirectedEdge[a, b], DirectedEdge[b, c], DirectedEdge[a, c]},
  VertexLabels -> "Name",
  VertexLabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, 14},
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1],
  GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"]
```

> Graph[{a [DirectedEdge] b, b [DirectedEdge] c, a [DirectedEdge] c},
>     VertexLabels -> "Name", 
>    VertexLabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, 14}, 
>    PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1], GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"]

On the other hand, replacing `FontFamily -> "Helvetica"` with `"SR"`restores success.

```
Graph[{DirectedEdge[a, b], DirectedEdge[b, c], DirectedEdge[a, c]},
  VertexLabels -> "Name",
  VertexLabelStyle -> {"SR", Bold, 14},
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1],
  GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"]
```

Conjecture: A list can not be substituted for `Directive` when one or more of its elements is a rule.

Comment: That conjecture should be boldfaced and on top!

Comment: `Directive` is still unnecessary for this case, `VertexLabelStyle -> {{FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, 14}}` will work.

Comment: @IstvánZachar. Why do you think it needs to be made so much more visible? Because it is valuable or because it is egregious?

Comment: @xzczd. Good point, although I personally find the `{{...}}` form very strange and rather ugly (because I can think of no logical reason why double-listing should make a difference).

Comment: @m_gold Well, I found it really valuable, but then xzczd made the idol fall down. I really thought that you nailed it. Still, the conjecture is valid for one level of `List`.