# Multiple styles in ExclusionsStyle

Tags: plotting, style

In my plot I have used an exclusion at the asymptote like this:

```
Exclusions -> {x == -1}, ExclusionsStyle -> Dashing[Medium]
```

The question is, how can I make the dashes at the asymptote Dashing AND Red? It seems that Mathematica only accepts either Dashing or Red, but not both. Any ideas?

I have tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
Exclusions -> {x == -1}, ExclusionsStyle -> {Red, Dashing[Medium]}
```

Thanks

[image: Plot]

Comment: Look up `Directive[]`.

Comment: Also look at: [In what situation is the use of Directive required?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24635/27951)

Comment: This question should really have been close as duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24635/3066

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those cases where one can use [`Directive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Directive.html) or wrap the list of exclusions in another list.

```
Plot[E^(-(1 + x)^(-1)), {x, -3., 2.}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-3., 2.}, {-0.5, 5.}}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0., -0.5}, 
   Exclusions -> {-1}, 
   ExclusionsStyle -> {{Red, Dashing[Medium]}}, Blue]
```

[image: plot]

In my plot, the 2nd element of the `ExclusionsStyle` list is set to `Blue` and sets the color of the boundary markers. That explains why two levels of listing is needed. It also explains why `Dashing[Medium]` has no effect on the OP's plot -- a dashed boundary marker is invisible.